# Way to run animations one after the other

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, qml, qtquick2

How to run animations one after the other? I tried to use `SequentialAnimation`, I've also tried to use multiple states and `id` inside `NumberAnimation` with restart but all of them failed. Extending duration to longer values (e.g.: `1000` or `2000`) also didn't work. I searched inside documentation but there are no such examples for `Canvas` (either for based types).

Referring to the code below ([source](http://woboq.com/blog/animations-using-the-qtquick-canvas.html)), could someone explain how it should be implemented:

```
import QtQuick 2.0 

Canvas {    
    id: canvas
    width: 256
    height: 256

    property bool arrowFormState: false
    function toggle() { arrowFormState = !arrowFormState }

    property real angle: 0
    property real morphProgress: 0
    states: State {
        when: arrowFormState
        PropertyChanges { angle: 180; target: canvas }
        PropertyChanges { morphProgress: 1; target: canvas }
    }
    transitions: Transition {
        RotationAnimation {
            property: "angle"
            direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
            duration: 500
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            property: "morphProgress"
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
            duration: 500
        }
    }

    onAngleChanged: requestPaint()
    onMorphProgressChanged: requestPaint()

    renderTarget: Canvas.FramebufferObject
    renderStrategy: Canvas.Cooperative

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d')
        // The context keeps its state between paint calls, reset the transform
        ctx.resetTransform()

        ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

        // Rotate from the center
        ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180)
        ctx.translate(-width / 2, -height / 2)

        var left = width * 0.25
        var right = width * 0.75
        var vCenter = height * 0.5
        var vDelta = height / 6

        // Use our cubic-interpolated morphProgress to extract
        // other animation parameter values
        function interpolate(first, second, ratio) {
            return first + (second - first) * ratio;
        };
        var vArrowEndDelta = interpolate(vDelta, vDelta * 1.25, morphProgress)
        var vArrowTipDelta = interpolate(vDelta, 0, morphProgress)
        var arrowEndX = interpolate(left, right - vArrowEndDelta, morphProgress)

        ctx.lineCap = "square"
        ctx.lineWidth = vDelta * 0.4
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
        var lineCapAdjustment = interpolate(0, ctx.lineWidth / 2, morphProgress)

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(arrowEndX, vCenter - vArrowEndDelta)
        ctx.lineTo(right, vCenter - vArrowTipDelta)
        ctx.moveTo(left + lineCapAdjustment, vCenter)
        ctx.lineTo(right - lineCapAdjustment, vCenter)
        ctx.moveTo(arrowEndX, vCenter + vArrowEndDelta)
        ctx.lineTo(right, vCenter + vArrowTipDelta)
        ctx.stroke()
    }
    Timer { repeat: true; running: true; onTriggered: toggle() }
}
```

Comment: The problem was because in my code I forgot about: onMorphProgressChanged: requestPaint(). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

It should work like this:

```
transitions: Transition {
    SequentialAnimation {
       running: true

       RotationAnimation {
            property: "angle"
            direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
            duration: 500
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            property: "morphProgress"
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
            duration: 500
        }
    }
}
```

So the first would be `RotationAnimation` and the second - `NumberAnimation`.

Also the docs say:

> Animations defined within a Transition are automatically run in
>   parallel, so SequentialAnimation can be used to enclose the animations
>   in a Transition if this is the preferred behavior.

So it should work for you. If not, please, post the code you tried and which did fail.

[QML SequentialAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sequentialanimation.html)